# Oracle Apex - SQL Where with Case

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a really simple query using Group Checkboxes:

```
P1_CHECKBOX_1
P1_CHECKBOX_2
```

And a really simple query to refresh an Interactive Report based on those two items like this:

```
select
name,
last_name
from Emp_table
where 
(case
    when instr(:P1_CHECKBOX_2, name)>0 
    then instr(:P1_CHECKBOX_2, name)>0
    else instr(:P1_CHECKBOX_1, last_name)>0
end) = 1
```

The idea is to filter the IG using the checkboxes.
Both items have an independent dynamic action that refreshes the report (affected elements the report region).
Is there anything I'm missing here?
I'm getting this error:
ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! ORA-06550: line 161, column 8: ORA-00905: missing
keyword

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `THEN` and `ELSE` clauses should return values and not contain comparisons:

```sql
select name,
       last_name
from   Emp_table
where  case
       when instr(:P1_CHECKBOX_2, name)>0 
       then instr(:P1_CHECKBOX_2, name)
       else instr(:P1_CHECKBOX_1, last_name)
       end > 0
```

or, more simply, without the `CASE` expression:

```sql
select name,
       last_name
from   Emp_table
where  instr(:P1_CHECKBOX_2, name)>0 
or     instr(:P1_CHECKBOX_1, last_name) > 0
```

Comment: Question please, how can one prioritize them?
E.g. If I select a check on Checkbox Item 2...I want my report to use only this Item even if Checkbox 1 is being selected.
Thanks!

Comment: @JB999 Why would you want to prioritise in the `WHERE` clause? Either one condition is true `OR` the other condition is true and in either case the row will be returned; it is irrelevant which priority they are matched in within the `WHERE` clause.